# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() never called

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to discover bluetooth devices nearby. I followed tutorials but I can't figure out why `onReceive()` method is never called. Even though `startDiscovery()` is successful,the method `onReceive()` never gets called. I have added the proper permissions to the manifest

```
if(adapter.isDiscovering()) {
                adapter.cancelDiscovery();

                if (adapter.startDiscovery())
                    test.setText("Searching >>>");

                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            }
}
if(!adapter.isDiscovering()) {

                if (adapter.startDiscovery())
                    test.setText("Searching >>>");


                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
                registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
            }
```

```
 private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public Receiver() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> ();
                devices.add(device);

                listAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context,R.layout.activity_bluetooth_connection,devices);
                pairedDivices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pairedDevices);
                pairedDivices.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                if(devices.isEmpty())
                    test.setText("no devices");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you registered the receiver in your manifest?

Comment: yes I have. still not working

Comment: what version of android?

Comment: 8.1 (oreo version)

Comment: Check your logcat for errors. Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something. Are you doing this on a real device on in an emulator?

Comment: on a real device